# Expandable List View refresh automate?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

My Scenario is that, I have one Expandable List View add i dynamically and child in the list. my child layout is like that.

[image]

When i click on edit button with respective item i am open dialog box get input from user and on click update respective detail update into database.

Now from database retrieve all data and set to expandable list view.
Hope you understand my scenario.

its my code for update dialog.

```
try {
                alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        if (mET_asset_amount.getText().toString().isEmpty() || mET_asset_return_pretext.getText().toString().isEmpty() || mET_asset_texrate.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                            // mErrorMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please fill detail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            assetTable = new AssetTable(mContext);
                            UtilClass.asset_amount = Integer.parseInt(mET_asset_amount.getText().toString());
                            UtilClass.asset_return_pretext = Integer.parseInt(mET_asset_return_pretext.getText().toString());
                            UtilClass.asset_texrate = Integer.parseInt(mET_asset_texrate.getText().toString());
                            Log.e("Inputed data", UtilClass.asset_amount + " " + UtilClass.asset_return_pretext + " " + UtilClass.asset_texrate);
                            assetTable.assetUpdate(assetChild.getmAssetName());

                        }

                    }
                });
                alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                alertDialogBuilder.show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error in add asset", e.toString());
            }
```

that's code in my adapter.
it's update data correctly but it not refresh expandable list view .

my question is that when i click on "ok" button update dialog i want to refresh  expandable list view . i stuck in that problem. please anybody can help.

thank you very much.

Comment: Use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: where to use this? in adapter or activity and what is this adapter

Comment: Do it just after `assetTable.assetUpdate(assetChild.getmAssetName());` that's where you've made the change. You're probably in the adapter in this code so you can just use `<AdapterClass>.this.notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: ExpandableListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged(); give is not an enclosing class

Comment: @JasonOfEarth not working..

Comment: Can you post your adapter code?

Comment: already post adapter code

Answer (score 1):

After the update operation is done in the "Ok" button of your dialog. you need to fetch the data in the Adapter's List/Array again and call the notifyDatasetChanged() method.

for example:

```
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new       DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if(mET_asset_amount.getText().toString().isEmpty()
|| mET_asset_return_pretext.getText().toString().isEmpty() 
|| mET_asset_texrate.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        // mErrorMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Please fill detail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        assetTable = new AssetTable(mContext);
                        UtilClass.asset_amount = Integer.parseInt(mET_asset_amount.getText().toString());
                        UtilClass.asset_return_pretext = Integer.parseInt(mET_asset_return_pretext.getText().toString());
                        UtilClass.asset_texrate = Integer.parseInt(mET_asset_texrate.getText().toString());
                        Log.e("Inputed data", UtilClass.asset_amount + " " + UtilClass.asset_return_pretext + " " + UtilClass.asset_texrate);
                        assetTable.assetUpdate(assetChild.getmAssetName());

//Fetch the data from the database again in the Adapter/add the new item
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

                    }

                }
            });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what is adapter here...?

Comment: **adapter** is your ExpandableListview's adapter

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` whenever you want to refresh or update your list element.

```
public void notifyDataSetChanged ()

Added in API level 1
Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.
```

see this link:- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetInvalidated()

`notifyDatasetChanged()` works if you use the add(), insert(), remove(), and clear() on the Adapter.

You must have to call this from main thread otherwise it not reflect any thing to adapter.

see this link for implementation of notifyDatasetChanged:- http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I overrode notifyDataSetChanged in my ExpandableList adapter. I deleted the old data and added updated data.

```
   @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        treeSetMain.clear();
        treeSetMain.trimToSize();
        treeSetSub.clear();
        treeSetSub.trimToSize();
        treeSetMain = new ArrayList<>(MyDataBase.getInstance(context).getAllMainGroups());
        treeSetSub = new ArrayList<>(MyDataBase.getInstance(context).getAllSubGroups());

        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```